# Injecting an enum with Spring

Tags: java, spring, enums

I'm trying to inject java enum through spring context using `<util:constant`.

Here's what I've done. In my spring config, I've following entry

```
<util:constant id="Content" static-field="com.test.taxonomy.model.MetadataTypeEnum.CONTENT_GROUP" />
<util:constant id="Category" static-field="com.test.taxonomy.model.MetadataTypeEnum.CATEGORY" />   

<bean id="ADSKContentGroup" class="com.test.taxonomy.model.ADSKContentGroup" scope="prototype">
  <property name="name" ref="Content" /> 
</bean>
```

Here, I'm trying to leverage an Enum ADSKContentGroup to be injected in my bean's (ADSKContentGroup) ame property.

Here's the enum :

```
public enum MetadataTypeEnum {
  CONTENT_GROUP ("ADSKContentGroup"),

  private String metadataType;

  private MetadataTypeEnum(String metadataType) {
    this.metadataType = metadataType;
  }
  public String getMetadataType() {
    return this.metadataType;
  }
}
```

Here's the bean :

```
public class ADSKContentGroup extends Metadata {
  public ADSKContentGroup(){
  }
}
```

The bean extends from a base class which has the setter for name attribute

Here's the class definition:

```
public class Metadata {
  private MetadataTypeEnum name;
  private String value;

  public String getName() {
    return name.getMetadataType();
  }

  public void setName(MetadataTypeEnum name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}
```

In runtime, I'm getting the following exception

```
ERROR com.test.taxonomy.plugin.TaxonomyPluginImpl  - Error in creating metadata mapping :Error creating bean with name 'ADSKContentGroup' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [com.test.taxonomy.model.MetadataTypeEnum] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Original must not be null  
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ADSKContentGroup' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/beans.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert property value of type [com.test.taxonomy.model.MetadataTypeEnum] to required type [java.lang.String] for property 'name'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Original must not be null
```

Not sure what's going wrong with my approach.

Any pointer is highly appreciated.

- Thanks

Comment: what version of java and what version of spring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Metadata` class is ill-designed JavaBean, it does not conform to the spec: The setter uses a parameter of type `MetadataTypeEnum`, but the return type of the getter is `String`.